# Graphical corruption during Linux startup and shutdown - should I be worried?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, shutdown

For the last month, when starting up or shutting down my laptop under Linux, I would get graphical corruption. Startup has an colour inverted, grainy rendition of what should be displayed while shutdown has a red background with all the text replaced by grey rectangles.

At the very least this affects Fedora, Ubuntu and Xubuntu. Windows is not affected. Outside of startup/shutdown the system is fine.

Should I be worrying about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get flickering on startup sometimes. I haven't had any data loss or anything like that.

This [fix from the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1282338) might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the **`nomodeset`** kernel parameter. In my case it solves the flicker and graphic madness ;)

Here my complete grub line for the kernel:
`linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-10-generic root=/dev/mapper/vg-lucid ro quiet splash nomodeset`